# Notion API paginated endpoint returning lists of varying lengths

Tags: language-agnostic, notion-api

I'm running into a puzzling Notion API issue. I have implemented pagination as described [here](https://developers.notion.com/reference/pagination) in the developer docs. When I recursively hit the **Search** API endpoint to return all my pages, the results seem to have random slight variations. For example, I have ~ 1,250 pages in my Notion account. One time it will return 1,247 pages, and the next time it will return 1,249 pages. In both these requests, the vast majority of the pages (1,245) remain constant, but a couple are (seemingly) randomly dropped or added on. In addition, the cursor values that are returned will usually be the same, but will sometimes randomly change as well. I've exhausted pretty much all trouble-shooting I can think of off the top of my head and haven't run into anything glaringly obvious. I'm curious if anyone else has run into this or something similar?

Comment: Is this still an issue and are you using the same request each time? What is the request you are making?

Comment: @adlopez15 Yes, this still appears to be an issue. I can literally run the exact same request  3 times in a row, and each time I will get slightly different results. In particular, this has occurred when I'm hitting the [search](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-search) endpoint. I haven't checked to see if I have the same issue with other paginated endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as (seemingly) randomly as it started, it is now no longer doing this. I wonder if, since the API is in beta, there was some feature that was buggy? Idk, but this is closed anyways.